# How should I write an eloquent continue?

Tags: c++, loops

So its often come up in my classes that i need to be able to have a program where the user can do things multiple times.

so I write something like

```
boolean continue=true;

while (continue) {
    //do code
    boolean isAnswerGood=false;
    while (!isAnswerGood) {
        cout << "Do you wish to continue" << endl;
        string answer;
        getline(cin, answer);
        if (answer=="y") //or something else
            isAnswerGood=true;
        else if (answer=="n") {
            isAnswerGood=true;
            continue=false;
        } else 
            cout << "That wasnt "y" or "n" please type something again" << endl;
    }
}
```

This seems bloated and a lot of code for something so simple. Im willing to think outside of the box with this one, so if anyone can give me a clue as to a better solution to this, id appreciate it.

Comment: I would avoid using the word `continue` for a variable name, as it is a keyword in C-like languages. `retry` would be better.

Comment: What language is this? there may be language constructs that unbloat this. I don't see how it can be 'unbloated' You can move code around and perhaps use boolean logic instead of if/then but that's really a coders preference and may not be supported in your code. i.e. you could put a `continue=(answer!="n");` outside the main loop if your language supports it, but I don't know that you would agree that it is any simpler. I think it is myself.

Comment: Many answers here seem to think you want to do something many times. Your code just wants to do something once, but wants to check with the user until they enter a correct response.

Comment: @PeterWood: I don't think so. The asker only shows a comment where the "do something" part goes, but it is inside the `while`.

Comment: Peter is sort of right, i want to simply enable the user to choose how many times he wants to do something. It may be once, it may be many times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but that is about the right amount of code.  C and C++ are relatively verbose compared to some other languages.

However, if this is a common problem, you can abstract it out and make a function out of it.  The function would be very similar to what you already have, but then you would call it something like this:

```
boolean again = true;
while (again) {
    // do code
    again = ask_user("Do you wish to continue?", "y", "n");
}
```

The arguments to `ask_user()` should be the question to ask, the answer to accept that means "yes", and the answer to accept that means "no".  The error message (about an unexpected input) can be made using the second and third arguments, so we don't really need to pass it in.

Of course, the problem could be even more complicated than this... what if your code will be used by non-English speakers?  If you needed to handle localization, you could make a basic function that has all strings passed in including the error message, and then make a wrapper that the user calls with a language specification.  Here's an example, this time using the "infinite loop" in C++:

```
for (;;) {
    // do code
    if (!ask_user_yesno("en_us"))  // locale: English, USA
        break;
}
```

Comment: continue is a keyword.  The first block of code won't compile, at least not with gcc.

Comment: @Matt, you are right.  I only used that word because it was in the example, but now that you pointed it out I changed the code.

Answer (score 4):

Break it into separate functions. (Almost always the answer to "how do I write an eloquent...?")

For example:

```
do {
  // something
} while (UserWantsMore());

/////////

bool UserWantsMore() {
  std::string answer = GetAnswer("Continue?");
  while (!GoodAnswer(answer))
    answer = GetAnswer("Please answer 'yes' or 'no'!");
  return IsAnswerYes(answer);
}

bool GoodAnswer(const std::string& answer) {
  return !answer.empty() && (answer[0] == 'y' || answer[0] == 'n');
}

bool IsAnswerYes(const std::string& answer) {
  return !answer.empty() && answer[0] == 'y';
}

std::string GetAnswer(const char* prompt) {
  std::cout << prompt << std::cend;
  std::string answer;
  std::getline(std::cin, answer);
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Totally overkill man! this actually makes it harder to read than the simple case.

Comment: It might be slightly harder to read, but it's easier to understand, as the function names give a good indication as to what the author's intent was.  That makes bugs easier to spot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just wanting to make what you already have do the same thing with a little less code, this will work.

```
string answer="y";

while (answer=="y") {
    //do code
    for(;;) {
        cout << "Do you wish to continue" << endl;
        getline(cin, answer);
        if ((answer=="y")||(answer=="n")) break;
        cout << "That wasnt \"y\" or \"n\" please type something again" << endl;
    } 
}
```

---

Slightly less code, but slightly more obfuscated:

```
string answer="y";

while (answer!="n") {
    if (answer=="y") {
        //do code
    } else {
        cout << "That wasnt \"y\" or \"n\" please type something again" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Do you wish to continue" << endl;
    getline(cin, answer);
}
```

---

Here's a version that uses `<termios.h>` to get the answer. It uses more code, but behaves more "eloquently".

```
int getch (void)
{
    int c;
    struct termios oldt;
    struct termios newt;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    newt = oldt;
    newt.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    c = getchar();
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    return c;
}

bool again (std::string prompt, std::string yes, std::string no)
{
    bool doyes = false;
    bool dono = false;
    for (;;) {
        std::cout << prompt;
        int c = getch();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        doyes = (yes.find(c) != yes.npos);
        dono = (no.find(c) != no.npos);
        if (doyes || dono) break;
        std::cout << "Type [" << yes << "] for yes, or [" << no << "] for no.";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return doyes;
}
```

You can use it as others have suggested:

```
do {
    // the interesting code
} while (again("Do you wish to continue? ", "y", "n"));
```

---

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
void DoYesCode()
{
   // Do the code for the yes stuff...
}

...

do{
    cout << "Do you wish to continue" << endl;
    string answer; 
    getline(cin, answer);
    if (answer=="y")
       DoYesCode();
    else if (answer=="n")
       break;
    else 
       cout << "That wasnt 'y' or 'n' please type something again" << endl;
} while(true);
```